# In Quiz website timer and CSS are not working simultaneously

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
const handleClick = (a) => {
    setSelectedAnswer(a);
    setIsPaused(true); // Pause the timer
    setClassName("answer active");
    delay(3000, () =>
        setClassName(a.correct ? "answer correct" : "answer wrong")
    );
    delay(5000, () => {
        if (a.correct) {
            correctAnswer();
            delay(1000, () => {
                setQuestionNumber(prev => prev + 1);
                setSelectedAnswer(null);
            });
        } else {
            wrongAnswer();
            delay(1000, () => {
                setStop(true);
            });
        }
        setIsPaused(false); // Unpause the timer
    });
};
```

In this code when selectedAnswer got some value then for timer stopage isPaused is used to stop timer but then className should also be changed to "answer active" but no css work after the timer stops ?
Please help me to get rid of this problem

I am not getting anything , I have tried ChatGPT also asked my collegues

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: "no CSS works2 - have you used your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is/isn't being applied?